# React-router loading component within nested components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

I am using react-router and understand the basics however I am trying to understand how to correctly load/link all components when routes are found in different areas.

I have a layout component that contains a Sidemenu, header and content components.

It looks something like this:

Masterlayout.js is the main page that is never going to change

```
return (

      <Layout>
           <SideMenu />
        <Layout>
          <Header>
            <HeaderItems />
          </Header>
          <Content>
             -- Load components here depending on the clicked SideMenu
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>

  );
```

In SideMenu.js

```
return (
    <Router>
      <Menu
        className="menu-container"
        mode="inline"
        defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
      >
        <Menu.Item key="1">
          <Icon type="test" />
          <span>first</span>
          <Link to="/first" />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">
          <Icon type="clock" />
          <span>second</span>
          <Link to="/second" />
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>

      <Route path="/first" component={firstComponent}/>
      <Route path="/second" component={secondComponent}/>
    </Router>
  );
```

How can I pass my components within Content? The Link To works however it does not currently load the component. If I load SideMenu within content it loads both the navigation bar and component no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Masterlayout.js

```
<Layout>
    <SideMenu />
    <Layout>
        <Header>
           <HeaderItems />
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/first" component={firstComponent}/>
                <Route path="/second" component={secondComponent}/>
            </Switch>
        </Content>
    </Layout>
</Layout>
```

in SideMenu.js

```
return (
      <Menu
        className="menu-container"
        mode="inline"
        defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
      >
        <Menu.Item key="1">
          <Icon type="test" />
          <span>first</span>
          <Link to="/first" />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">
          <Icon type="clock" />
          <span>second</span>
          <Link to="/second" />
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
  );
```

You should have a `Router` somewhere up in the tree. It doesn't have to be located near the routes. You can put it in your `src/index.js` where you load the app and render it to the dom

Comment: Thanks Mo, I did this previously however my Router was in MasterPages. Can I ask why it didnt work when I had it in MasterPages but worked in my App.js component, a higher level component?

Comment: the Router component needs to be higher in the component tree because it uses React Context to make the routing information available to all its descendants. By putting it higher in the tree, you're guaranteeing that all components have access to that routing context. If you're interested in learning more about it, check the source code of `Router`, to see how it uses context: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d44786392fddfd8f5452fe64da9d31e34cf23b09/packages/react-router/modules/Router.js#L55